# While Loop Or For Loop In Other Functions in RUST

Tags: loops, for-loop, rust, while-loop

I am new to Rust.
It would be nice if someone could help me.
The first code works, but not the second one.

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    let y = 3;
    println!("{} Liftoff!", countdown(y));
}

fn countdown(mut y: u8) -> u8 {
    let coun = loop {
        println!("{}", y);
        y -= 1;

        if y == 1 {
            return (y);
        }
    };
}
```

I thought `while` or `for` give back a value automatically.
How can I give back a value in `while` or `for` loop?

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    let y = 3;

    println!("{} Liftoff!", countdown(y));
}

fn countdown(mut y: u8) -> u8 {
    while y != 0 {
        y -= 1;
    }
}

/*fn countdown () -> u8{

    for y in (1..4).rev(){

    }
}*/
```

Comment: loops will not return a value unless you pass out the value when breaking the loop. If you replaced `return` with `break` in the first example, then `coun` would be assigned to the value instead of immediately returning. You may find it helpful to try following an online course/tutorial to lean the basics of flow control in languages like C, Java, Python, etc. There are tutorials for Rust too, but the other languages have many more existing courses and there are not many functional differences in how flow control is performed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Loops are *expressions* in rust. This means that you can write `let x = loop { /* ... */ };`. However in your first snippet you do not return value from the loop (that you are trying to assign to `coun`), but are instead returning from the function. You could rewrite it to be like this:

```rust
fn countdown (mut y:u8)-> u8 {
    loop {
      println!("{}",y);
      y-=1;
      
      if y==1 {
          break y;
      }  
    } // notice the lack of semicolon here! 
}
```

Here you have a loop that returns a `u8` (as en expression) and then this value is returned from the function.

2. You return value from loop expression by using `break` statement. In your second snippet there is no `break`, so this `while` loop returns a unit type `()`. Since this is the last expression in the function rust tries to return it, and gives you an error, since you said that this function should return `u8`, but you are trying to return `()`. To fix this "problem" you could add a `break` statement however this would be odd to use a `while` loop like that.
3. `for` loop is very different from `loop` and `while`. You should think of it as *for each*. You can still use `continue` and `break` statements. However you cannot use `break` with a value. `for` loop must always evaluate to `()`.

## Bonus

Did you know that you can give loops labels? This is very useful when you have nested loops (for example when you have main game loop and inside it a loop for event queue). This means that you can write code that looks like this:

```rust
let test = false;
let test2 = true;

let x = 'outer: loop {
    'inner: loop {
        if test {
            break 'outer 42;
        } else if test2 {
            continue 'inner;
        } else {
            continue 'outer;
        }
    }
};
```

You can read detailed documentation about *loop expressions* and *loop labels* [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html).

Comment: "To fix this "problem" you could add a break statement however this would be odd to use a while loop like that" - note that you can't `break` with the value in this case, however.